# Android seems to render box-shadow like its an 8bit PNG, anyone know how to resolve this?

Tags: android, css, mobile

Im trying to give a div a deep inset box-shadow of `-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 83px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);` but testing this in Android seems to make this effect look like its an 8bit PNG. Im testing on 2.3, iOS displays completely fine. Anyone encountered this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Android 4.0 and earlier does not support `inset` or blur radius on `box-shadow`. See the footnote on http://caniuse.com/css-boxshadow.